# Is this a way of defining "global variables" in C?

Tags: c

Is this way of defining a "global variable" valid / a good approach?
While I would like this variable to be used whenever the header file is included to store program states.

```
/* global.h */
...
typedef struct {
    int some_count;
    ....
} ProgramState;

ProgramState *GetProgramState()
...
```

```
/* global.c */
...
#include "global.h"

ProgramState *GetProgramState()
{
    static ProgramState *prog_state = NULL;
    if (!prog_state) {
        prog_state = (ProgramState *) malloc(sizeof(ProgamState));
        *prog_state = (ProgamState) {
            .some_count = 1
        };
    }
    return prog_state;
}
...
```

```
/* main.c */
#include "global.h"

int main(void)
{
    GetProgramState()->some_count++;
    printf("%d\n", GetProgramState()->some_count);
    return 0;
}
```

While I know this way induced some overheads (while calling the method?), and there are ways like `extern` (using the `extern` way requires a specific initialize function).

Please let me know if there are other alternatives, thanks!

Comment: It's a viable technique, although you need locking as well as the static variable if you have multiple threads.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Resembles the "Singleton" design pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively an [accessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method). An accessor gives control over how a variable is accessed, allowing checks (e.g. validation) to be performed, and allowing the specific implementation of the variable to be changed. Using accessors is a common and perfectly acceptable programming paradigm.

As you mentioned, the alternative would be to access the variable directly. And while you could initialize it (contrary to what you said), it can only be initialized using a constant expression (e.g. `NULL`, but not `malloc(sizeof(ProgamState))`).

Comment: That `GetProgramState` is not able to control or check anything as it returns a pointer giving full access to the caller.

Comment: @Gerhardh You are mistaken. The caller can't change `prog_state` in the least. They can change `*prog_state`, sure, but that's not relevant to anything Isaid.

Comment: That is true if you assume it is all about `prog_state` inside that function. But from the given example I would say, it is about the data where it points to. This can be changed easily as demonstrated in `GetProgramState()->some_count++;`

Comment: Re "*That is true if you assume it is all about prog_state inside that function*". It is all about that, since that's all my answer mentioned. Anything else, such as what you are saying, is off-topic. Even the OP didn't ask for that.